# How much elements has a subset of a group with even elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can someone help me on this problem? Thank you so much!

> Let $G$ a group with even number of elements and $A$ a subset such that $A = \{ g \in G | g^2 = e \}$. Show that $A$ has an even number of elements.

My try:

> Hence $G$ has even elements that means $G$ has elements with order 2. Let $x \in G$ such that $x^2 = e$ (by Cauchy) then $x = x^{-1}$.. The same thing for $x \in A$. 
>   It's easy to show $A$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: $A$ is not necessarily a subgroup of $G$, so it would be quite remarkable if that were "easy to show"

Answer (score 8):

The map $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is an involution $G\setminus A\to G\setminus A$ without fixed points, therefore $\lvert G\setminus A\rvert$ is even. This proves that $\lvert A\rvert$ is even.

*Remark:* Proving that "$A$ is a subgroup of $G$" is either very easy or very hard, depending on one's propension towards drawing false conclusions: it's actually false in general.

Answer (score 0):

I've got another interesting solution in time.
By Cauchy theorem exists elements in $A$ with $ord(x) = 2$, $x \in G$.
Let $y \in G$ be an element such that $ord(y) > 2$ so $y$ and $y^{-1}$ can be coupled in groups $(y, y^{-1})$ so hence $G$ has even number of elements and number of elements such that $ord(y) > 2$ is  even we get $A$ has even number of elements.